# Align image at the bottom of text and have that text surround the image at the same time

Tags: html, css, image, text, alignment

I have researched for 30 mins to solve my problem without success... I want to have an image that always stays on the bottom right of some text but have part of the text to its left so that it always ends at the image's bottom.

I tried floating the image but it only stayed on the right, while the text was entirely on top of it.
I don't want to put the image somewhere in the text, so that it comes up to this alignment. I want to somehow accomplish this by having this alignment of the code at all times :

```
 <p>Random text prevailed sincerity behaviour to so do principle mr. As
 departure at no propriety zealously my. On dear rent if girl view.
 First on smart there he sense. Earnestly enjoyment her you resources.
 Brother chamber ten old against. Mr be cottage so related minuter is.
 Delicate say and blessing ladyship exertion few margaret. Delight
 herself welcome against smiling its for. Suspected discovery by he
 affection household of principle perfectly he. </p>

 <img src='image.jpg' alt='bla'>
```

Here's an example :

[image]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/erenyener/rWa6D/  There are so many ways to do it, but in my case, you can put image inside the paragraph and give it a float as a right

Comment: @MehmetErenYener The problem is *aligning* the bottom of the image to the bottom of the text